# What is the simplest way to map a folder on the file system to a url in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, virtual-directory

Here's my problem...  I have a small prototype app (happens to be in Grails hosted on AWS) and I want to add the ability of the user to upload a few (max 10) images.  I want to persist these images on disk on the server machine, in a folder location which is outside my WAR.

I realise that there is probably a super-scalable solution involving more web servers and optimised static asset serving, but for the approximately 100 users I am likely to get, it's really not worth the effort and cost.

So, what is the simplest way I can have a virtual folder from my url map to a physical folder on disk?  I sort of want...

```
http://myapp.com/static
```

to map to a folder which I can configure e.g.

```
/var/www/static
```

so I can then have in my code...

```
<img src="/static/user1/picture.jpg"/>
```

I don't particularly mind whether the resulting physical folders are directly browsable.  Security will eventually be an issue, but it isn't at the start.

So, what are my options?  I have looked at virtual hosts on the apache site, but it feels more complicated than I need.

I don't want to use the Grails static rendering plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up building my own servlet to read in a file and stream it to the output.  The catch is that if you don't support mime types, gzip, etags, and cache-headers (such as Last-Modified) this can be very inefficient.  I ended up coding all of these (and using ehcache for server side caching), but it's not simple.

However, this StackOverflow question has a number of useful responses.

[What is the simplest way to map a folder on the file system to a url in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438483/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-map-a-folder-on-the-file-system-to-a-url-in-tomcat)

One of the more appealing options seems to be FileServlet.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html